# get data from third child of class member with using selenium php server

Tags: php, selenium

i've been breaking my head over this one for a day. i have this hierarchy of html content, repeating itself in the page:

```
<div class="layout-header">
    <div>
       <a rel="ajax-href-view" href="https://www.dummy.com/view/d67617688d2b55"><img src="edit.png" title="edit Website.com Below Content 728x90" alt="edit"></a>
       <a rel="ajax-href-view" href="https://www.dummy.com/view/d9360769dd2b41"><span style="text-transform:uppercase;">Edit</span> Website.com Below Content 728x90</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

now,i am trying to get the text from the second `<a>` tag and also the end of the href string i.e, the string after the last / in the href attribute.

i was able to play with `className` like this:

```
  $attr = $this->webDriver->findElements(\WebDriverBy::className('layout-header'));
  foreach ($attr as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($value->getAttribute("style");
  }
```

just to see i can get some content from the class, but when i tried to get deeper in the hierarchy i got totally lost.
how can i get the first `<a>` href and the second `<a>` text while looping over the `layout-header` class elements? or if there is any other way i would love to hear about it...thx

Answer (score 0):

You can get it in one go with an [XPath expression](http://facebook.github.io/php-webdriver/classes/WebDriverBy.html#method_xpath):

```
WebDriverBy::xpath('//div[@class="layout-header"]/div/a[span = "Edit"]')
```

Here we are getting the `a` element, having `span` with text = "Edit", located inside the `div` located inside the `div` with `layout-header` class.